# Nuxt 3 and prom-client

Tags: nuxt.js, prometheus, nuxt3, prom-client

Anyone knows how to use prom-client in Nuxt3 app?
Which place I should insert `collectDefaultMetrics` function?

Within nuxt.config it not working, or throw an error:
`a metric with the name process_cpu_user_seconds_total has already been registered`